# How to remove an item from ListView (Array list) in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, listview

I was building a simple app, where a user can add one liners to a list view and then on clicking that item in the list view, that item will be removed.

I have completed the adding part, however, I am facing a problem when it comes to removing the item by clicking on it. My java code is as follows:

```
 package com.example.supornochaudhury.schedulerapplication;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import static com.example.supornochaudhury.schedulerapplication.R.id.parent;
    import static com.example.supornochaudhury.schedulerapplication.R.id.select_dialog_listview;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView timesTableListView;
    ArrayList<String> Works = new ArrayList<String>();



    public void startWork (View view){
        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.toDoEditText);
        String name=edit.getText().toString();

        Works.add(name);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Works );
        timesTableListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timesTableListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.timesTableListView);
        timesTableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                timesTableListView.removeViewAt(position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After running this application on my phone, I am able to add without any issues, however, when I am clicking on any of the items, the app crashes.

I would be indebted if anyone helps. :)

Comment: I haven't android studio now, but `removeViewAt???` whice view?? try `remove` or `removeAt` (or something like this.. but not view...)

Comment: Can you post the log cat output?

Answer (score 0):

Use arrayAdapter as global.
then remove  an item from array list and use notifyDataSetChanged() to adapter

```
timesTableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Works.remov(position);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please first remove the item.that is clicked from the Works ArrayList and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter